# Problems associating a hyperlink to a shape / image

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, epplus

I need to create a "button" in a worksheet. The button's function would be to redirect the user to another worksheet. E.G. in the worksheet "Graphics", there's a button that redirects the user to the worksheet "Menu" when clicked on.

I can't simply set a hyperlink in a cell, because the user would need to click in the cell's value to get redirected. It's also harder to make it look like a proper button, so I've tried setting a hyperlink in a shape, but, apparently, EPPlus doesn't support that.

The last solution I came up with was to create different images, representing the buttons I want to use, and set a hyperlink to them. Here's the code im using currently:

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(imgFolder + Consts.MENU_BUTTON))
{
    worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Menu", img, new ExcelHyperLink("Menu!A1"));
}
```

This doesn't work.. but if I try to set a hyperlink in a cell using a similar code, it works:

```
worksheet.Cells[3, 3].Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink("Menu!A1", "Menu");
```

I've tried to twist the first chunk of code I posted in every way I could try, but still, I can't seem to get the results I want..

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Perhaps someone has been in a similar situation and found another way to deal with this problem ?

Best regards,
Erick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(imgFolder + Consts.MENU_BUTTON))
{
    worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("Menu", img, new ExcelHyperLink("#Menu!A1", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Note the hash in "#Menu!A1", and the use of UriKind.Relative.

Comment: It worked!I never would have guessed that.. thank you very much!